# Float section in a Bootrstrap column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've created two rectangles on the full screen's width (so without `<div class="container">`).
I've used bootstrap for this.

Now, to have the content of those rectangles still in the middle of a page the left section (`col-sm-5`) has `width:calc(1170px / 12 * 5)` and the right section has accordingly `width:calc(1170px / 12 * 7);`

The right section looks fine, but I need to make the left section to be on the left side of the container.

`float:right` doesn't work, 
`position:absolute; right:0;` makes it look totaly wrong.

The code:

```
<div>
 <div class="row equal">
      <div class="col-sm-5 double-left">
           <section class="double-left">
           Left side
           </section>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-7 double-right">
           <section class="double-right">
           Right side
           </section>       
      </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.double-left {background:#4aaaa5;}
div.double-right {background:#35404f;}

section.double-left {
  width:calc(1170px / 12 * 5);
  position:relative;
  float:right;
}

section.double-right {
  width:calc(1170px / 12 * 7);
}

.equal, .equal > div[class*='col-'] {  
   display: -webkit-box;
   display: -moz-box;
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;
   flex:1 0 auto;
}
```

PS. I use `.equal` to make the columns have the same height.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
section.double-left {
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Since it's inside a col-sm-5 and it has only one child element, you can put the width on 100% (to fill all the space) and text-align will make the text float to the right

Comment: but I don't want the text to be right-aligned. Did you see the live example?

Comment: I saw, I guess I don't understand what you want then, please explain better what you want to achieve

Comment: so right now the width of the `section.double-left` is OK. what I want to achieve is that it's not on the left but on the right side of the `div.col-sm-5`